# bind multiple rows to a textbox for edit + update

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, ado.net

I have created a Windows form using Visual C# - this contains a rich textbox. I have an Access database containing text in 2 cells (rows) of 1 column.

What I want to be able to do is:

1. Concatenate the contents of rows within my Access table
2. Display the concatenated rows in the rich textbox on my form
3. Be able to edit the contents of the rich textbox and save the changes back to the table

So far I have bound the table to the rich textbox, though only 1 cell (row) is being displayed - the data that I will be concatenating is text, each cell in the table won't have a unique value - each cell simply holds a section of a paragraph.

I have read the Update command & Retrieve command of ADO.Net, though it seems that data must have a specific value i.e. `Select Name from People where value = Peter`

Is there a chance of me achieving what I want to achieve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Instead, I would store each value in a separate column in the database, and then bind each textbox to that field.

Comment: Thanks for replying - I guess that is the only, if slightly unwieldly way of doing it! However, that makes the updating functionality impossible doesn't it because the user won't know what words are being replaced where?